# Can anyone explain this Selenium error and why selenium works on one query but not another

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I asked this before and got no responses so I'll try again.

I have been having issues with my selenium and chromedriver that I can't seem to figure out. I have one code that runs just fine and does everything it is supposed to. However, I have another that give me the error code in the picture. If anyone could help, I would certainly appreciate it as I had no luck finding anything online. I especially don't understand why one program runs with no issues and the other doesn't. I don't know if potentially the website is blocking it from running? Is that a possibility?

Code that runs just fine:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

beginningTime = time.time()
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
time.sleep(3)

browser.get('http://droughtmonitor.unl.edu/Data/DataDownload/ComprehensiveStatistics.aspx')
browser.maximize_window()
dropdown = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="dnn_ctr1009_USDMservice_CompStats_2017_aoiType_chosen"]""")
```

Code that doesn't work:

```
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


beginningTime = time.time()
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
symbols = ['WYNN', 'FL', 'TTWO', 'NKE']
myColumnHeaders = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']

dfs = []

for c in range(len(symbols)):
    url = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/'+symbols[c]+'/historical'
    print('read url')
    time.sleep(3)
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)
    print('here')
```

It prints 'read url' and opens the webpage but never gets to the print 'here' step. It then throws the note in the command prompt that is attached as a picture. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Error code I'm getting]
[image: Further Notes error throws]

Comment: Where are you declaring url?

Comment: where did you init/assign value to  `url` in this code line `browser.get(url)`

Comment: try with straightway providing url instead of url in get

Comment: Okay so that was just an error on my part because I had been testing stuff and forgot to revert to the original code. I've updated the code to pick up the url as seen above. However, that is not the issue that is causing my error as I still have the exact same issue. It prints read url but never prints 'here' and the errors I've posted below occur still.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to tell your driver to direct you to a url and passing the parameter `url` to it. this parameter is not previously defined in your code.

if you are trying to get the current url from the driver, use:

```
browser.current_url
```